# JavaScript setMinutes() behaves wrongly around DST ending

Tags: javascript, date, dst

When the US Daylight Saving ends, we switch our clocks back 1 hour and this makes the 1 AM hour happen twice on that day. However, JavaScript behaves strangely for timestamps in the second 1 AM hour (after clock switch) and keeps reverting them to the daylight time of 1 hour before. This can be seen when trying to use `setMinutes` and `setHours` methods.

This code sets the minutes of a date to its current minutes value, and behaves as expected (browser has `America/Los_Angeles` time zone):

```js
let date = new Date("2021-07-07T09:40:00.000Z");

console.log(date.toLocaleString("en-us", {timeZoneName: "short"}));
// "7/7/2021, 2:40:00 AM PDT"

date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes());

console.log(date.toLocaleString("en-us", {timeZoneName: "short"}));
// "7/7/2021, 2:40:00 AM PDT"
```

But this code doesn't:

```js
let date = new Date("2021-11-07T09:50:00.000Z"); // DST ended on Nov 7 at 2 AM

console.log(date.toLocaleString("en-us", {timeZoneName: "short"}));
// "11/7/2021, 1:50:00 AM PST"

date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes());

console.log(date.toLocaleString("en-us", {timeZoneName: "short"}));
// "11/7/2021, 1:50:00 AM PDT" <-- Wrong time zone
```

So the Date object can correctly print timestamps in the second (standard time) hour, but it interprets the date as still in daylight time when using `setMinutes()`.

Is this expected behavior? It seems odd that `date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes())` should alter the date.

Comment: Why are you calling `date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes())`? That's basically a no-op

Comment: This is pretty demonstrably not a noop: we _expect_ it to be a noop, and yet instead it does something very weird, where setting a value to what it already is changes the date by an hour.

Comment: @Phil Isn't that the point? It should be a no-op, but it prints differently.

Comment: This is a browser implementation detail and is not a language issue.

Comment:  I basically missed the point of the question. My apologies

Comment: @RandyCasburn know of a JS engine in which this doesn't happen? Because Chrome, Firefox, _and_ Node all do this.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - Safari

Comment: If I set `timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles"` in the options, I see both reporting as _"11/7/2021, 1:50:00 AM PST"_ in the second example (Chrome v95.0 MacOS). Seems difficult to reproduce this in another local timezone

Comment: Is this a display issue or an actual time error? Specifying a timezone or printing to UTC returns the correct moment in time.

Comment: @RandyCasburn which one? because if I run these snippets in Safari, the result for the second snippet is still two different strings in both v14 and v15

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - hmm, I'm running 15.1. I'll take another look when I get a chance, but that does not change the fact that the JavaScript spec does not address how to handle DST.

Comment: This isn't about DST itself, though. This is more about "the timezone changes when you use something that should be a noop": the LocalTZA section of the spec says that the "how to deal with daylight savings" is implementation specific, but also that irrespective of that implementation, when tlocal represents local time repeating/skipping due to time zone transitions, tlocal must be interpreted using the time zone offset before the transition. So as far as the spec seems to suggest, that second time should stay PST, not become PDT.

Comment: If you follow the algorithm for [*setMinutes*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.setminutes) it creates an entirely new TimeClip after running [*MakeDate*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-makedate) and [*MakeTime*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-maketime) so likely the engine still must resolve whether it's the first 01:50 or the second. See [*LocalTime*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-localtime).